# is it possible to backtrack to parent tag from current element, until it finds title attribute present in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, getattribute

```
   <div class="one" title="I have a title">
     <div class="two">
       <div class="three">
         <label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="four" readonly="" value="on">

           <div class="clickable"></div>
            <div class="four">iam a text</div>
         </label>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The element with class "`clickable`"is my target element to click and i would like to get parent element which has title in the attribute

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'iam a text')]/preceding::div[@class='clickable']"));
```

**Example Pseudo code would be**

```
while(hasParentElemets()){
if(currentElement.hasTitle())
 break;
else
currentElement = currentElement.parent();
}
```

Comment: `<div class="_1p7h2j">` doesn't have a `title` attribute.

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks for the reply ... Now I have edited my question. Can you evaluate again

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the parent element using xpath. try something like this.This will find a parent element which contains a title attribute.

```
WebElement myTitleElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clickable']/ancestor::div[@title]"));
```

Comment: Can't we get "title" attribute without creating new WebElement? As I already created  WebElement element.

Is there any way of writing expression in the getAttribute() function
Example : element.getAttribute("/*/div[@title]")

Comment: getAttribute returns the value of any attribute in the given element. note the difference between attribute property and its attribute value.  If it is question of finding the correct element with certain   attribute or attribute which contains certain values, you can use this xpath approach.